# xcodebuild exited with error code 65 when compiling in Travis

Tags: ios, xcode, travis-ci

We are currently setting our XCode project to build and test in Travis.
We are performing a `pod install` and then using the following command:

`xcodebuild clean test -workspace XXX.xcworkspace -scheme XXX -destination \"platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7\" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=\"\" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO`

It appears that it is failing to compile a file from the BNRCoreDataStack pod:
`/BNRCoreDataStack/Sources/Bundle+CoreDataModelHelper.swift`, with the following error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSManagedObjectModel'` (and then it exits with code 65). Looking into this class, we can see that the initializer of `NSManagedObjectModel` is indeed optional, so we are not sure what the error may be.

Running the same command in our local machine works fine.

Additional info: We are using xcode9 and Swift 3.0.

---

[Actual code from BNRCoreDataStack:](https://github.com/bignerdranch/CoreDataStack/blob/21c8366d907443c90bcd4e74bb84454139d9bccd/Sources/Bundle%2BCoreDataModelHelper.swift)

```
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
    static private let modelExtension = "momd"
    /**
     Attempts to return an instance of NSManagedObjectModel for a given name within the bundle.
     - parameter name: The file name of the model without the extension.
     - returns: The NSManagedObjectModel from the bundle with the given name.
     **/
    public func managedObjectModel(name: String) -> NSManagedObjectModel {
        guard let URL = url(forResource: name, withExtension: Bundle.modelExtension),
            let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: URL) else {
                preconditionFailure("Model not found or corrupted with name: \(name) in bundle: \(self)")
        }
        return model
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code that is causing this compiler error?

Comment: Sure, just edited the original question

Comment: Very interesting. You're sure that the failing compilation is using that exact same code? Maybe something is getting wrongly optimized away. I wonder whether it would go better if the code were rewritten. But I suppose you can't do that. You might take this problem to the authors of the BNRCoreDataStack. Or Travis (I'm uncertain). Or Apple.

Comment: Yes, we are `Using BNRCoreDataStack (2.2.1)`, both locally and in Travis, which uses this exact code. We just emailed Travis support, I will update this question if we have any luck.